# Magento 2 wysiwyg editor does not load folder

Tags: magento2, php, wysiwyg

I have issue with magento 2 wysiwyg editor it does not load folder even storage root folder. I have check for permission pub/media/wysiwyg its showing with 777 permission.
Also I have checked for ajax request for loading folder and images.
I show only one ajax eg.

1. http//:your-site.com/admin/cms/wysiwyg_images/index/key/fce7ea57790a8af9e04f9fa7ab30e4497b34daeb28de37dc406eb0fdecdeda88/target_element_id/cms_block_form_content/?isAjax=true

But doesn't call ajax for folders and images eg.

1. http://your-site.com/admin/cms/wysiwyg_images/treeJson/key/624549f545378e9b2a23ad0da8bb91687a1e8a12d472784775e7bce3eaaad856/?isAjax=true
2. http://your-site.com/admin/cms/wysiwyg_images/contents/key/c22d1a702aef715d8a353b5954bbe9828904dc8976ddcaa18b47f24c7c3f3036/?form_key=BIU8Gw1orqmYYBvn&node=root&isAjax=true

Here is my screenshot https://prnt.sc/j0be60

Can anyone knows why it is heppens, or where can I look for the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're facing the exact same problem today, the images upload fine, the directory just doesn't load. There are no errors in the console either. Did you solve this at all?